# How to configure VAO and VBO for custom made Structure

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to construct a bar.

First I declare a structure

```
struct VertexFormat
    {
        glm::vec3 positions;
        glm::vec3 normal;
        glm::vec2 texCoord;
        VertexFormat(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 norm, glm::vec2 coord) : positions(pos), normal(norm), texCoord(coord)
        {   }
    };
```

and then I configure the VAO and the VBO

```
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, data.size() * sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Nothing gets drawn when I issue the drawing commands

```
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My question is: am I defining the offsets for the data in the buffers correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with this code:

First, the amount of data uploaded to the EBO is wrong. The size of the data has to be given **in byte**. Assuming that `indices` contains unsigned integers, the code should be:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then, `stride` describes the offset between two consecutive vertices in the buffer, not the total size of your data. In your case, every vertex starts `sizeof(VertexFormat)` after the previous one.

The correct code should be:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexFormat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
```